# Nested promise returns undefined

Tags: javascript, promise, protractor, chai, cucumberjs

I'm trying to write tests with cucumber.js using Protractor and chai-as-promised.

In my Page object I have these fragments of code:

```
var menusOnListElements = element.all(by.repeater('menu in menus').column('menu.name'))

this.isMenuListed = function(menu) {
    return menusOnListElements.each(function(element) {
        return element.getText().then(function (name) {
            if (menu.name === name) {
                return true; //this is executed
            }
        });
    });
};
```

and in my step definition code I do:

```
var menu = {};
menu.name = 'Abc';
expect(new MenusPage().isMenuListed(menu)).to.eventually.be.true.notify(done);
```

When I run this test I get

> expected undefined to be true

which means that the isMenuListed method returned undefined instead of true. However, I debugged it and I can see that 'return true;' statement is executed.

Am I missing something about how promises work in this case?

Comment: What is this `.each` function? What does it do? `isMenuListed` doesn't seem to return a single `Promise<boolean>`.

Comment: Think about what `menusOnListElements.each(...)` returns

Comment: right, it looks that each function does not return anything, so this is why I'm getting undefined here. Thanks for pointing this out. Any suggestions how to make it work?

Comment: the value of all those must be true for the test to be successful?

Comment: No, if any is true, the test is successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can also apply [`reduce()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.reduce) here:

```
this.isMenuListed = function(menu) {
    return menusOnListElements.reduce(function(acc, element) {
        return element.getText().then(function (name) {
            return acc || menu.name === name;
        }, false);
    });
};
```

The drawback here is that we go through every single element in the `menusOnListElements` and don't stop if we find the matching menu. Aside from that, `reduce()` would resolve here in a `true` or `false` which defines if a menu is listed or not.